# AVFoundation created video won't upload to Facebook

Tags: facebook, video, upload, avfoundation

I'm working on an app that create a video from a collection of frames using AVFoundation, adds an audio track and uploads to Facebook. I've previously had this working successfully, but it now appears to be failing and I can't find the issue with the format of the video.

An example video is available here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/6p8u11

It should be a Quicktime movie with H.264 and AAC audio. This *ought* to be ok, but perhaps something about the frame size or frame rate are an issue?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks,

J

Comment: What isn't working? Are your API calls failing or succeeding but then when you attempt to retrieve the video it fails?

Comment: The video is uploaded successfully, but then I receive a notification from FB that the video cannot be processed. This was working on earlier revisions. I did further investigation and found out that the breaking change was modifying the frame rate of the video. I suspect, then, that I'm using `CMTime` incorrectly, but these videos play fine on the desktop and through the camera roll - it's only FB that rejects them.

Comment: Does it meet the requirements here? https://www.facebook.com/help/www/218673814818907 If so, it may be a bug and if you have clear repro steps you could file a bug report in the API bug tracker

Comment: It's definitely caused by some aspect of the framerate. I want a framerate of 10fps, so I set the timescale of my `CMTime` to 10 and increment the numerator with each frame. With the denominator set to my desired 10, this doesn't work (although the video plays with any media player). However with the denominator set to 1 (ie. 1fps) it *does* work... This is very strange.